# insert to the middle of a line in a textfile sed

Tags: sed

I am new to sed script. I have been researching how to add text to a line in file.

so the line I have in the text file looks like this

```
hosts allow = 192.168.122. 172.24.0
```

i want to add IP so line looks like

```
hosts allow = 192.168.122. 192.12.0 172.24.0
```

Through trial and error I only have:

```
sed -i '/allow/ s/.*/&,192.12.0./' testfile
```

which gives:

```
hosts allow = 192.168.122. 172.24.0. 192.12.0.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Now define what you mean by correct position. IMHO position implies a number, like 10 from the left margin. But it could be counting by words, so in your case, after the first word? Other interpretations come to mind, so please clarify. (Why couldn't the new text be the first on the line?) .Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Check this test :

```
$ cat file1
hosts allow = 192.168.122. 172.24.0
hosts allow = 111.111.111. 222.222.222 333.333.333

$ sed -E 's/(.* = .*)( .*)/\1 george \2/g' file1
hosts allow = 192.168.122. george  172.24.0
hosts allow = 111.111.111. 222.222.222 george  333.333.333

$ sed -r 's/(.* = .[^ ]*)(.*)/\1 george \2/g' file1
hosts allow = 192.168.122. george  172.24.0
hosts allow = 111.111.111. george  222.222.222 333.333.333
```

This test uses sed with extended regex support (-E or -r switch) and capturing groups enclosed within ( )

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too vague to say for sure (do you want to add a string to the middle of a set or after the first one or before the last one or at a fixed location or something else) but this might be what you're looking for:

```
$ sed 's/ [^[:space:]]*/& 192.12.0/2' file
hosts allow = 192.12.0 192.168.122. 172.24.0

$ sed 's/ [^[:space:]]*/& 192.12.0/3' file
hosts allow = 192.168.122. 192.12.0 172.24.0

$ sed 's/ [^[:space:]]*/& 192.12.0/4' file
hosts allow = 192.168.122. 172.24.0 192.12.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an awk solution, which I find more legible than sed solutions:

```sh
awk '$1$2$3 == "hostsallow=" { $NF="192.12.0 $NF" } { print }' \
  testfile > tmp && mv tmp testfile
```

This takes the first three columns and ensures they concatenate to "hostsallow=" without spaces (I doubt you'll run into a `host sallow = …` line), then takes the value of the last column (identified as `NF` for the number of fields and whose value is identified with a `$`) and assigns the new value, a space, and the old value to it.  All lines are then printed.  Warning, this will collapse whitespace (in this case, I see that as a feature).

Unfortunately, awk doesn't have a `-i` option the way sed does, so this has to be saved in a temporary file and then put back on top of the original file.